Rayleigh dissipation function for quadratic drag
Is there a way to adapt the Rayleigh dissipation function to be used for quadratic drag instead of linear drag? I was thinking that something like
$$\mathcal R = \frac{1}{3}(c_d)(v)^3$$
where $c_d$ is the drag coefficient ,
might work although I am not sure.

Yes, that's basically right.

For quadratic drag the generalized force term in the Euler-Lagrange equation is $Q=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2c_DA$. We want $Q=-\frac{\partial R}{\partial v}$ so $$R=-\frac{1}{6}\rho v^3c_DA$$ in which case, yes, would satisfy the condition $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=-\frac{\partial R}{\partial v}$$
however the rayleigh disippation function for linear drag gives half of the rate of energy dissipation whereas here it gives a third of the rate of energy dissipation, and the sign is different ($P=\frac{1}{2}\rho v^3c_D A$)
